# Web3 "Transaction ran out of gas" on method that creates a contract

Tags: web3js, gas-limit

I have the following Solidity code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Parent {
   function createChild() public {
        new Child();
    }
}

contract Child {

}
```

Which I'm calling with web3 like this:

```
const item = await managerABI.methods.createChild().send({
   from: accounts[0],
   gas: '5000000',
})
```

Although the function is very simple and the gas limit is very high, I'm getting the error `Transaction ran out of gas`.  Additionally, the full error message shows `"gasUsed": 21577`, which appears to mean that the actual gas used in the operation was well below the limit.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried assigning the value of `new Child()` to an `address` variable?

Comment: Yes, still getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be a very simple issue.  I was tweaking my solidity code and updating the ABI, but not updating the address of the `Parent` contract after redeploying.

I actually had other getter methods that were working because I was not making changes to those, which added to the confusion.

Make sure to update your ABI and contract addresses after deploying!